# Formatting MongoDb response for API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, restify

I'm trying to retrieve a collection in MongoDb and the problem is the API already responds even though the processing is not yet done. So basically what I'm trying to do is retrieve the results using `find`, iterate through the results using `foreach`, and push each row to an array.

I've tried a variety of suggestions but none work so far. Below is a rough idea of what I'm trying to pull off.

```
get: async function (req, res, next) {
        let messagesArray = []
        let sessionId = req.query.session

        client.connect(err => {
            try{
                const collection = client.db("xxxxxxx").collection("xxxxxxx")
                let results = collection.find({},{sessionId:sessionId}) 

                for (const result of results){
                   order = {"text" : order.partner+", "+order.order+ ", "+order.quantity}
                   messagesArray.push(order)
                }
            }
            catch(e){

            }

            client.close()

            res.send(200,{messages:messagesArray})
        })

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop will execute asynchronous so before your for loop is getting finished res is sent so try for the following

```
get: async function (req, res, next) {
        let messagesArray = []
var counter = 0;
        let sessionId = req.query.session

        client.connect(err => {
            try{
                const collection = client.db("xxxxxxx").collection("xxxxxxx")
                let results = collection.find({},{sessionId:sessionId}) 

                for (const result of results){
                   order = {"text" : order.partner+", "+order.order+ ", "+order.quantity}
                   messagesArray.push(order)
                   counter++;
                   if(counter == results.length) { 
                     client.close()
                     res.send(200,{messages:messagesArray})
                   }
                }
            }
            catch(e){

            }
        })

    },
```

Comment: +Subburaj this answer is close enough. `results.length` should just be changed.

Answer (score 0):

use `await` to wait for result to available :

```
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

get: async function (req, res, next) {
        let messagesArray = []
        let sessionId = req.query.session


        const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }).catch(err => { console.log(err); });

        if (!client) { return;}


            try{
                const collection = client.db("xxxxxxx").collection("xxxxxxx")
                let results = await collection.find({sessionId:sessionId}) 
                console.log(results);      

                // ...    

            }
            catch(e){
                 console.log(e);
            }
            finally {
                client.close();
            }


    },
```

Comment: I tried this one but there is no response except this warning: [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated. I'm using Node 10.16.3 by the way.